# How to pass a jquery value in a div or form and assign it in a hidden textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

just want to ask a question about passing a value using jquery and assigning it in a form hidden textbox. Here's my code i hope you can help me.

```
**homepage.php**
 <?php
    $cat_id = $row['salescatid'];
 ?>
 <input type="button" name="add_comment" data-value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>" value="Add Comment" class="comment" />
 .
 .
 <div id="comment_category">
 <!-- DISPLAY COMMENT HERE -->
 </div>
 <?php echo form_open('CATEGORY_CONTROLLER/INSERT_COMMENT'); ?>
 <div id="comment_add" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="cat_id" /> //Here's the problem how can i get the value from my jquery?
    <input type="hidden" value="sales_category" name="type"/>
    <label>Write your comment</label><br />
    <textarea name="comment_category" style="width: 50%; resize: none;"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="COMMENT" class="btn btn-primary btn-SMALL"/>
 </div>
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
 .
 .
 .
 //Here's my jquery
 $(".comment").click(function(){
       var id = $(this).attr('data-value'); //This is the value of the button, problem is how to pass it in my comment form?
       $("#comment_add") .show();
       //alert(id);
 });
```

Please help me guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to assign a value to an input element and use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select the input field using the name attribute

```
$('input[name="cat_id"]').val($(this).attr('data-value'))
```

Ex:

```
 $(".comment").click(function(){
       var id = $(this).attr('data-value'); //This is the value of the button, problem is how to pass it in my comment form?
       $('input[name="cat_id"]').val(id)
       $("#comment_add") .show();
       //alert(id);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name="cat_id"]').val(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding an id to the element so you can easily select it:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="cat_id" name="cat_id" />
```

Alternatively you can also select it by its name as suggested in other answers and then you can set its value easily with jQuery:

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-value');
$("#cat_id").val(id);
```

Hope this helps!